# AngularJS - where to place third-party plugin defaults?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization

Let's say that we have a third-party plugin where we can set some options as attribute value.

```
<button options="prop.options">
```

In the controller we have:

```
/**
 * More about $scope.prop
 * - No need to access $scope 
 * - It should access $window
 * - It's pretty large object (e.g. 100 lines)
 */
$scope.prop = {options: {}};
```

I'd want to keep controller as thin as possible, but what's the best place to move this object? What's considered as good practice in cases like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of data, creating a service is often the way to go. This provides a centralized source of your config data and can be injected into whichever component needs to use it.

```
app.service('pluginOptions', function($window) {
    return {
        options: {
            prop1: 'x'
            prop2: 'y'
        }
    };
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function(pluginOptions, $scope) {
    $scope.prop = pluginOptions.options;
});
```